# OpenCvSharp.CvConst class missing?

Tags: c#, opencv, package, nuget-package

I am working on a project with OpenCvSharp.

I want to port [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findchessboardcorners) script to C#:

```cpp
bool patternfound = findChessboardCorners(gray, patternsize, corners,
        CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH + CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE
        + CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK);

if(patternfound)
  cornerSubPix(gray, corners, Size(11, 11), Size(-1, -1),
    TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1));

drawChessboardCorners(img, patternsize, Mat(corners), patternfound);
```

and I got everything to work, except for the `CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER` etc.
I just can't find theese constants! I looked for them in every package I could think of and searched the entire assembly tree for them with no success.

In the [source code](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_2410/search?q=cvconst&unscoped_q=cvconst) and the [documentation](https://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp_2410/html/f6bbfd34-a465-73ad-fa49-3f6eee2aeec2.htm), `CvConst` is used but I can't find that class!

I tried installing various NuGet Packages and ended up with the following:

- OpenCvSharp4
- OpenCvSharp4.runtime.win
- OpenCvSharp4.Windows

(the first ones were installed by the last one)

So **where is OpenCvSharp.CvConst?**

Comment: "In the source code and the documentation" -- yeah, but then you're looking at code and documentation for version 2.4.10 while you're trying to using version 4.x (based on the package names).

Comment: well I found the enums now in ```OpenCvSharp.ChessboardFlags``` and ```OpenCvSharp.CriteriaType```, should I delete my question or answer it? I'm not sure since this isn't really a rechnical question, it's just irritation caused by the changing class structure in OpenCvSharp

Comment: Up to you, this could potentially be of use to someone. | Generally a change in the first (major) component of version number signifies API breaking changes. That was definitely the case with OpenCV (both 2->3 and 3->4). I'm not really surprised the C# bindings changed as well. Good to keep that in mind.

Comment: I’d suggest answering your own question rather than deleting it.